# Json deserialize Dictionary<key,value> return as null

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Just a quick one!

I have three object classes.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Children child{ get; set; }
}

public class Children
{
    public Dictionary<string, item> item{ get; set; }
}

public class item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON string I am using:

```
        {
            'name': 'Child1',
            'Children': {
               'item-1253': {
                   'id': 'car',
                   'type': 'car'
               },
               'item-4343': {
                   'id': 'car',
                   'type': 'car'
               }......
           }
        }
```

Used:

```
test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json);
```

The output was `"item": null`. Can I ask why? How can I access all the properties within this item object as there will be multiple items per child and the item object name is dynamic e.g. `item_id12434`. I would like the object to be on its own, how do I achieve this? Would something like this work? `List<Dictionary<string, item>>`

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, `'` is not legal string delimiter in json, are you sure it's not `"` ?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes I have tried ""key"" still null and ' is legal (it can be serialised with it)

Comment: You have named your property `child`, whereas the json property is named `Children`, this mismatch will not be handled automatically. Note that it is the *name* of the object property that is used, not its type. There are, however, additional problems.

Comment: For instance, you have `Dictionary<string, item>`, whereas your "item" in your json is a string. If you change `child` to `children`, and change your dictionary property to `Dictionary<string, string>`, it will deserialize. You do not need the `item` type.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Just for my understanding. I have used a dictionary because the object name is dynamic and changes. I have created a type as it will hold all the properties for that object which includes a list, array etc. How can I map it correctly if the name is dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED** example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7TK008

---

Please, look at the working example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/eiMEkr

You make two issues:

1. wrong param name *Children* - should be **child**
2. wrong definition of a dictionary object

```
    const string json = @"
                {
                   'name':'Child1',
                   'child':{
                      'item':{
                         'dict_item':{
                            'id':'car1',
                            'type':'car2'
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }";

   var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json);
```

Comment: I see. Thanks vlad I have a question. 'item' will have a unique name which is dynamic. I think I implemented it wrong. I wanted multiple items like this:

'child':{
                      'item':{
                       
                            'id':'car1',
                            'type':'car2'
                         
                      }, 'item2':{
                       
                            'id':'car1',
                            'type':'car2'
                         
                      }.

Please see my example above. Did I use Dictionary incorrectly?

Comment: From looking at your example its an object item {} that contains a list of multiple dict_item {} but I would like multiple item {} on its own

Comment: @Mask-dCodex: need to remove **Children**-class and define Dictionary in **Parent**-class directly, please look at the fixed example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your classes to look like this, and it will deserialize correctly.

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = @"{
                'name': 'Child1',
                'Children': {
                    'item-1253': {
                        'id': 'car',
                        'type': 'car'
                    },
                    'item-4343': {
                        'id': 'car',
                        'type': 'car'
                    }
                }
            }";

        // Way 1) Using POCO
        Parent parent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(str);

        // Way 2) Using dynamic
            dynamic deserializedDynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);

        // Way 3) Using JObject
        JObject deserializedJObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(str);
        List<JObject> childrenObjects = deserializedJObject["Children"]
                                        .Cast<JProperty>()
                                        .Select(x => x.Value)
                                        .Cast<JObject>()
                                        .ToList();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Children")]
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: JsonProperty for item is dynamic name e.g. the next one could be item-1213

Comment: Thanks for your response. the item itself is the unique id so the structure will look something like this.   {
            'name': 'Child1',
            'Children': {
               'item-1253': {
                   'id': 'car',
                   'type': 'car'
               },
               'item-4343': {
                   'id': 'car',
                   'type': 'car'
               }......
           }
        }

Comment: I get the first item output however there are two more item objects it needs to output

Comment: @Mask-dCodex Is `Children` an array of objects ?

Comment: No, it is just another object within children. please see my example json above :) I hope that makes sense

Comment: I dont think that fits my current structure as I have children in a seperate object which contains multiple items. So I cannot use [JsonProperty("Children")] as it is within children object. Looking at my object structure I would need to have the unique name as json property, is this correct?

Comment: @Mask-dCodex There's no other way to do it, apart from that. Or better de-serialize into a `JObject`

Comment: How can I achieve that as all properties in this object contains the same property but just a different object name.

Comment: @Mask-dCodex I didn't understand

Comment: Can you show how to implement this using the example above? So that I can type cast my JSON